# Operating on thrust::complex types with thrust::transform

Tags: c++11, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to use `thrust::transform` to operate on vectors of type `thrust:complex<float>` without success. The following example blows up during compilation with several pages of errors.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<float> > d_vec1(4);
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec2(4);

  thrust::fill(d_vec1.begin(), d_vec1.end(), thrust::complex<float>(1,1));

  thrust::transform(d_vec1.begin(), d_vec1.end(), d_vec2.begin(), thrust::abs< thrust::complex<float> >() );
}
```

I'm using CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu Xenial and compiling with clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 using `nvcc --std=c++11 main.cpp -o main`.

Main errors appear to be:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:17:105: error: no matching function for call to ‘abs()’
 gin(), d_vec1.end(), d_vec2.begin(), thrust::abs< thrust::complex<float> >() );
```

and

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/complex/arithmetic.h:143:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:105: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
 gin(), d_vec1.end(), d_vec2.begin(), thrust::abs< thrust::complex<float> >() );
                                                                            ^
```

No problem working on real floats, but no such with complex ones. I'm thinking there's a type error that I'm missing, but I'm very much still on the steep part of the learning curve with Thrust & templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is quite descriptive:

`thrust::abs<thrust::complex<...>>` is a **function** which expects **exactly one** parameter, see [thrust/detail/complex/arithmetic.h#L143](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/8e35dce3d2003f9e9f7eed8dac31be7f050c8b2d/thrust/detail/complex/arithmetic.h#L143):

```
template <typename ValueType>
  __host__ __device__
  inline ValueType abs(const complex<ValueType>& z){
  return hypot(z.real(),z.imag());
}
```

For your use case, you need to wrap that function by a **functor**:

```
struct complex_abs_functor
{
    template <typename ValueType>
    __host__ __device__
    ValueType operator()(const thrust::complex<ValueType>& z)
    {
        return thrust::abs(z);
    }
};
```

Finally, employ that functor here:

```
thrust::transform(d_vec1.begin(),
                  d_vec1.end(),
                  d_vec2.begin(),
                  complex_abs_functor());
```

Comment: This does the trick, but why does `thrust::negate<thrust::complex<float>>()` drop into the `thrust::transform()` call but `thrust::abs()` require wrapping in a functor? And the complaint about expecting one parameter—isn't `thrust::transform()` setting up parallel execution of the supplied unary operation against the input vector, writing results to the output vector?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus negate **is already** a functor, hence no wrapping require. What you did is you called `thrust::abs()` without a parameter within `thrust::transform`, but it requires that you supply a functor (=function **object**, an instance of a class/struct which provides `operator()`).

Comment: Looked at the definitions in thrust/functional.h and thrust/complex.h—makes sense now.